# Wp-admin/post.php 403 you dont have permission

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-20.04

I get the message

> You don't have permission to access this resource

when I add an article with a pic inside. But it works normally when there are no pics.

Configuration:

- Apache 2
- PHP 7.5
- WordPress 6.3
- Ubuntu 20.04

I have disabled all of your WordPress plugins, deleted `.htaccess`
permission for WordPress folder